# Codeigniter Form Validation for several input type text

Tags: codeigniter

I have group of text boxes like below

```
<input type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo set_value('sizes[]'); ?>" name="sizes[]"/>
<input type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo set_value('sizes[]'); ?>" name="sizes[]"/>
<input type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo set_value('sizes[]'); ?>" name="sizes[]"/>
<input type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo set_value('sizes[]'); ?>" name="sizes[]"/>
<input type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo set_value('sizes[]'); ?>" name="sizes[]"/>
```

then if I set validation rules like below

```
array(
'field'   => 'sizes[]',
'label'   => 'SIZES',
'rules'   => 'required|xss_clean'
),
```

then codeigniter check every input box for value. If every text box is filled up then codeigniter returns true. But I want to get **if anyone of them filled up then return true**

How can I do that??

Thanks

Comment: why do you use name="sizes[]" for html element's name?.

Comment: You can handle above one simply with a "||" (or) condition. but I can't understand your naming convention for html elements.

Comment: It is not quite clear from your code what do you want to achieve... Do you want to store the names of fields in the array sizes[]?

Comment: There are five text boxes. I would like to save their values in database.At time of form validation codeigniter check every input box for value. If every text box is filled up then codeigniter returns true. But I want to get if anyone of them filled up then return true

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom validation function in your controller and implement your own check on the input. First, you add a new function to the controller:

```
function _is_valid($str, $field_name)
{
    //First we see if the field name we are checking has multiple values
    if (!is_array($this->input->post($field_name))) 
        return false;

    //Let's get the posted values and see if any of them has a value:
    foreach ($this->input->post($field_name) as $value)
        if (strlen($value)) return true;

    //If we get here that means there was no value posted:
    return false;   
}
```

Next, change your rules for the field:

```
'rules'   => 'required|xss_clean'
```

To:

```
'rules'   => 'callback__is_valid[sizes]|xss_clean'
```

You can read more about custom validation functions here:

[http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks][1]